# Remove Pause Between UIView Animations

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm chaining together several animations and am having trouble removing the pause between consecutive animations.  First, I tried nesting UIView animations in completion blocks.  Since then, I've moved to this solution:

http://xibxor.com/objective-c/uiview-animation-without-nested-hell/

I think it's more readable, but I have the same pause problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably your animation timing, not pauses. By default, animations use ease in, ease out timing. That means that each animation starts out from 0, accelerates to full speed, and then slows to a stop. Then the next animation does the same thing.

If you want to chain a series of animations to create a seamless effect, you probably want to use linear animation timing. Look at the UIView class method animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Pass in UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear for the options parameter.

Comment: Setting the options to UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear did improve the animation, but there's still a slight pause between animations.  I think it's because the animations aren't run in a single animation block, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is in swift, too lazy to convert to objective C. Chain the animations together in the animation transaction block.

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(totalAnimationDuration, delay: 0, options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear, animations: {

    for (var i = 0; i < wayPoints.count; i++) {
        let nextWayPoint = wayPoints[i]

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(CGFloat(i) * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
            token.frame = CGRect(x: nextWayPoint.x + self.inset, y: nextWayPoint.y + self.inset, width: token.frame.size.width, height: token.frame.size.height)
        })


    }


}, completion: { success in


})
```

**Swift 3,4,5**

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: totalAnimationDuration, delay: 0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeLinear, animations: {

    for i in 0..<wayPoints.count {
        let nextWayPoint = wayPoints[i]

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: CGFloat(i) * relativeDuration, relativeDuration: relativeDuration, animations: {
            token.frame = CGRect(x: nextWayPoint.x + self.inset, y: nextWayPoint.y + self.inset, width: token.frame.size.width, height: token.frame.size.height)
        })


    }


}, completion: { success in


})
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, nor is it the language the question was asking about.

Comment: To be fair you didn't specify objective-c and it does answer your question.

Comment: @JeffCompton, it translates to Obj-C using the exact same API calls shown above. He is correct in stating that you must chain the animations in one foul swoop using something like a keyframeanimation. As you can see above, he dynamically creates the animations and adds them at once. This will chain the animations to a single keyframe animation. This prevents the delay your experiencing as there will be a delay waiting for the completion callback from the CATransation being committed.

Comment: You may want to look at iOS Core Animation Advanced Techniques by Nick Lockwood. It should explain advanced behaviors of CAAnimations leading you to understand why your issue is happening

Comment: No, the issue was the animation curve (hence the marked answer). It's awesome that it translates to Obj-C, but why would anyone want a mix of two different languages in the same project? Linking animations in the complete callback ensures that the animations will be executed at the correct time.  I'm hesitant to use a timer when the execution of each animation could be delayed because of phone resources.  If that happens, the timing will get screwed up. This answer isn't in the correct language, address the problem, and isn't as flexible as the answer linked in the question.

Comment: @A'saDickens Not until I have to.  The code base is Obj-C and this question was asked when that was the only language.

Comment: You don't mix the languages, you just use the API calls above in Objective-C... it's really not a hard translation. Also, there will still be a non linear animation even after removing UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear. There is a delay between the CATransaction beginning and calling the completion. I highly recommend you reading the book above to understand how animations work on CALayers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant after adding the UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear option

Comment: the names of the functions and classes used above are the same in objective - c and swift, you should be able to read the above and construct the exact same code in objective - c, and I could write the answer in java, c, or c++ to convey a concept of chaining animations since the question did not ask for a code snippet, it asked for a solution to choppy animations. Regardless of what you are programming in, your case being objective c, you should be able to take the concepts and apply them as needed to your scenario especially since the concepts are consistent through multiple languages.

Comment: You did not even give an example code snippet, that i could work with to re-write to convey the answer for your situation... -1 for not doing research and looking for a quick answer.

Comment: @A'saDickens I linked the solution that I went with in the question.